# Calling the same Controller with filtered data does not show updated view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having a scenario, where my first Index page loads with some detailed data in a row by row fashion. Also I have 3 text boxes RequestID, FromDate and ToDate to filter the data on the page Index view. Once I enter FromDate and ToDate in the respected text boxes and click on a button, through a javascript code I send FromDate and ToDate to the same Index controller to filter the data on the basis of FromDate and ToDate.

The Index controller gets called fine with the parameters FromDate and ToDate, also the data on the basis of FromDate and ToDate gets filtered properly.

But once the filtered data gets send to the Index view to get displayed it doesn't display the filtered data, in spite it shows the existing data.

Please find the below code for your reference.

Below is the Index Controller code.

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate, string status, DateTime? CloseDate)
        {
            IList<ActiveSupportIndexViewModel> activeSupport;

            if(StartDate == null && EndDate == null)
            {
                activeSupport = GetSupportIssueDetails(0, null, null);

            }
            else
            {
                activeSupport = GetSupportIssueDetails(0, StartDate, EndDate);
            }


            return View(activeSupport);
        }
```

where initially `activeSupport = GetSupportIssueDetails(0, null, null)` gets called and all data gets displayed.

After entering FromDate and ToDate and by clicking on button `activeSupport = GetSupportIssueDetails(0, StartDate, EndDate)` gets called and filters the data.

Below is the java script code written.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#Search").click(function () {
            var RID = $('#txtRequestID').val();
            var SDate = $('#txtStartDate').val();
            var EDate = $('#txtEndDate').val();
            var stat = $('#txtStatus').val();
            var CDate = $('#txtCloseDate').val();

            alert(RID)
            alert(SDate);
            alert(EDate);
            alert(stat);
            alert(CDate);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/Index',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: RID, StartDate: SDate, EndDate: EDate, status: stat, CloseDate: CDate },

                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.name);
                    //alert("Hello");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }

            });
            return false;

        });

    });
</script>
```

The javasctip also gets execute properly and sends the data to the controller with FromDate and ToDate.

Once getting Index controller called with FromDate and ToDate, the data gets filtered and gets send to the view. But the view does not appear with the fresh filtered data. Instead it displays the message box where it goes to below code of a javascript

```
success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.name);
```

and the existing data remains as it is.

Could anyone please help me to resolve the issue.

Please let me know in case of further information.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: An AJAX request is not like typing a URL in your browser's location bar. Nothing happens automatically with the response. If you're getting back a bit of HTML as a response, and you want that HTML inserted into the page, it's on you to change the DOM accordingly in your callback (where the alert is).

Answer (score 0):

In the Index page create a partial file with id, in there place the data which show the record.
on ajax success replace the partial file with the ajax data.
Refer this [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply, As I am a new to the MVC it is little bit difficult for me to understand your suggestion. Could you please elaborate the above suggestion. It could be appreciated if you could manage to send any reference link. Thanks.

Comment: refer the link. it ill be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

@Anand

Thanks you for your link. It works fine.

I post the below post of code I change according to your suggestion.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#Search").click(function () {
            var RID = $('#txtRequestID').val();
            var SDate = $('#txtStartDate').val();
            var EDate = $('#txtEndDate').val();
            var stat = $('#selectedRequestID').val();
            var CDate = $('#txtCloseDate').val();

            //alert(stat);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/partialIssueListDetails',
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: RID, StartDate: SDate, EndDate: EDate, status: stat, CloseDate: CDate },

                success: function (result) {
                    $('#IssueListDetails').html(result);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you again.